# How to get GID of group on host in Dockerfile

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm buidling a docker image which will serve als jenkins slave.
The image needs Java and SSHD. 
At the moment I have a docker container which can serve as jenkins slave. The user inside my slave is a user jenkins which I've created inside my dockerfile.

```
FROM java:8-jdk
ENV JENKINS_HOME /var/jenkins_home
ARG user=jenkins
ARG group=jenkins
ARG uid=999
ARG gid=999
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group} \
&& useradd -d "$JENKINS_HOME" -u ${uid} -g ${gid} -m -s /bin/bash ${user}
VOLUME /var/jenkins_home
WORKDIR /var/jenkins_home
```

Now I want that my jenkins-slave is able to build docker images. So every docker-command which my jenkins needs to run will be executed on this slave. Herefor I had to mount my docker sockets to my slave container.

I start my slave-container with docker-compose. Here you see how I start my slave:

```
jenkins-slave:
    build: ./slave
    image: jenkins-slave:1.0
    container_name: jenkins-slave
    volumes:
      - slave-volume:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
      ...
```

So now I had to change my Dockerfile because by default only root users are able to use docker. I want that my jenkins user can execute docker commands so I changed my Dockerfile and added:

```
RUN groupadd -g 983 docker \
&& usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Now I was able to perform `ssh jenkins@172.19.0.2` and execute docker commands with the jenkins user.
But this only works because the `gid` of my docker group on my host is also `983` (centos7). But on my Ubuntu the `gid` is `1001`. So then my whole setup will not work. So now my question:

Is there a way to a `gid` of your host inside  your dockerfile?

Comment: Easiest solution is to standardize on a gid across the organization, create this before installing the engine on any systems.

Comment: Maybe that's the only solution. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21184

Answer (score 2):

The `Dockerfile` is used at build time on a build host. The host that eventually runs your built image as a container is unknown at this stage so information about a host is not easy to look up. The same image would normally be used across all hosts so configuring a GID at build time is hard too.

BMitch's suggestion of using consistent GIDs (and UIDs) across an organisation is the best solution. This is a good idea generally, not only for docker. It helps with centralised user management, NFS likes it, LDAP is easier to move to.

If consistent GIDs are too hard to setup then there are a couple of ways to work around the issue...

#### Multiple images

If you have a limited number of GIDs to support you could create multiple images from your jenkins base image.

Tag: `my/jenkins-centos`

```
FROM my/jenkins
RUN groupadd -g 983 docker \
 && usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Tag: `my/jenkins-ubuntu`

```
FROM my/jenkins
RUN groupadd -g 1001 docker \
 && usermod -a -G docker jenkins
```

Then choose which image you run on which host.

#### Runtime

If you *had* to support variable `docker` GID's then the `groupadd` logic could run at container startup in a launcher script that does the group setup then launches Jenkins. You would probably need to mount `/etc/group` somewhere in the container to be able to look that host information up as well.